# Using MySQL python module to Insert or update if row exists

Tags: python, mysql, list, python-2.7, mysql-python

I am using MySql and python MySQLdb module. I want to insert a new row or update certain fields if the row already exists.

The list of tuples that contains the values to be entered looks like this;

```
ListTuple=[('A_val', 'B_val', 'C_val', 'D_val', 'C_val'), ('AA_val', 'BB_val', 'CC_val', 'DD_val', 'CC_val')]
```

The MySQL query looks like this;

```
query="""INSERT INTO table (A, B, C, D)
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)  
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             C= %s
      """

try:
    Cursor.executemany(query, ListTuple)  
    Db_conn.commit()
except:
    Db_conn.rollback()
```

Query execution fails with this code. Can someone point out what is wrong with it? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
query="""INSERT INTO table (A, B, C, D)
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)  
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             C= VALUES(C)
      """
```

Your query had 5 placeholders, but your tuples only have 4 values. You needed to duplicate `C`, but the `VALUES(C)` option will automatically get that from the original VALUES clause.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my question. My tuples actually do have 5 values. I have re-edited the question. Thanks for spotting it and sorry for misleading you.

Comment: But you have solved my problem!! I just removed the duplicate element from the 5-element tuple and made it a 4-element tuple, then applied your answer. It works!!

Comment: Again thanks for spotting the mistake. I have re-edited the question.

Comment: Glad it worked, although I'm not sure why it didn't work with the 5-tuples.

Comment: I was lucky as one of the elements is a duplicate. But what if there were no duplicates? How would the code look like? I think I will open another question on this issue.

Comment: If there are no duplicates, what's the problem? It will just insert everything fresh.

Comment: If there were no duplicates, I cannot use `C= VALUES(C)`. And my original code of using `C= %s` fails.

Comment: Sure you can. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause is only used as an exception when there's a duplicate. Otherwise it just does a normal INSERT using the `VALUES` clause.